# Как сделать триггер столкновения с границами экрана?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть объект, должен двигаться по тапу в разные углы экрана по порядку, эта часть реализована:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _targetPosition, player.GetSpeed());
```

_targetPosition - один из четырех векторов. объект должен переместиться в точку с этими координатами. 
Проблема возникает в написанием следующей функции - при достижении точки должен срабатывать какой-то триггер столкновения с границами экрана, при этом объект отлетает с затуханием скорости в сторону центра камеры. Раньше в этом месте стоял костыль.

Почитал про rigidbody.AddForce и transform.Translate оба метода выглядят как что то похожее на то, что мне нужно, а как скомбинировать не хватает фантазии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать физику то вам нужен `Rigidbody.Addforce` + `Collider` на вашем объекте. Тогда по границам экрана расставляете коллайдеры в качестве ограждения и физика сама за вас отработает отскок, вот только подстроить параметры надо. Правда если завязано будет на физику, то  как показывает практика будут сложности с тем чтобы состыковать остальным кодом где физика не используется, например резко изменить скорость объекта и т.п. Для того чтобы зафиксировать факт удара для обработки можете воспользоваться `OnCollisionEnter`, `OnCollisionExit` и `OnCollisionStay` (начало столкновения, конец столкновения и в процессе столкновения соответственно). Для этого добавьте эти методы в любой компонент на объекте где присутствует [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html).

Если же вам нужно свой алгоритм обрабатывать при столкновении, то можно в коллайдере выставить галочку `Trigger`, тогда отскока не будет, но факт касания двух коллайдеров можно будет отловить через  методы `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerExit`, `OnTriggerStay`. Или как вариант сделать рабочую зону в виде большого триггера и проверять, что ваш объект внутри через `OnTriggerStay`, иначе возвращать его в зону комфорта)

Ну и самый сложный способ это высчитывать координаты экрана, на каждом кадре проверять что объект с каким то размером выходит за пределы активной области и пытаться самому рулить процессом его перемещения.

Comment: Я пробовал AddForce, но мне нужна статичная скорость при движении объекта, плюс объект двигаться должен только из угла в угол, такой подход судя по всему не очень мне подходит. Тут есть еще такой момент, что на объекте висит пустой объект, который работает как таргет для камеры, для ее наклона в  зависимости от положении объекта, из-за чего смещается угол обзора камеры когда объект в каком-нибудь углу. Попробую расставить коллайдеры по углам и обрабатывать в ручную столкновения. Спасибо за советы.

Comment: По скорости можно после того как сделали `AddForce` следом сделать ограничение через `rigid.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rigid.velocity, VelocityLimit);` и тогда движение будет с одной скоростью.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо! если будут еще какие нибудь наставления/рекомендации буду благодарен